# How many languages is the Alexander Romance found in?

Tags: alexander-the-great, translation

How many languages does the *[Alexander Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Romance)* exist in? I am getting contradictory figures from different sources.

*I'm referring to translations known to us from premodern times.*

Albert Mugrdich Wolohojian writes in The Romance of Alexander the Great by Pseudo-Callisthenes, Columbia University Press, 1969, pg. 1:

> By the seventeenth century, the fanciful biography of the Macedonian
> world conqueror had appeared **in over eighty versions in twenty-four
> languages.**

Faustina Doufikar-Aerts claims to know of more than 25. In "The Arabic Alexander Romance: Mirror of a Bold, Clever, and Devout Prince", pg. 1, Faustina writes:

> The Alexander Romance of Pseudo-Callisthenes is one of the most
> widespread and prominent writings produced in world literature. In
> premodern times it was known in at least 100 translations,
> elaborations, and derivations **in more than 25 languages**, including in
> almost all the vernaculars of Europe, from Scandinavia and Spain to
> Georgia, and in the languages of the Islamized regions in Asia and
> Africa, from Mali to Malaysia.

On the other hand, a much higher figure is given by E.E. Rice in the *Encyclopedia of Greece and the Hellenic Tradition* pg. 52:

> There was a Byzantine metrical version of the Romance, and it was
> translated in the Middle Ages **into some 35 different languages**, among
> them Latin, Syriac, Arabic, Armenian, Hebrew, Ethiopic, and Hungarian.

Are any of these correct? What is the true number?

The [Wikipedia page of the Alexander Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Romance) lists 25 languages (the English and Scots section is counted as two), although it is evident that the "Scandinavian" section includes versions in both Old Norse and Old Swedish, raising the number to 26, and a Hungarian version is passingly mentioned in the beginning of the article as well as by Rice, giving us 27.  We are already in "more than 25" territory and there is no guarantee that all languages have been identified by this Wikipedia page. If Rice is right, then what are the missing 8 or so languages here? Could there be even more than 35? What is the true number?

Comment: Is there a "true number"? What does that mean? This is a non-copyrighted work that *anybody* who feels like can make a translation of. Its quite possible that multiple people have in their houses a translation they made themselves.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm referring to translations known to us from premodern times

Comment: I thought that was pretty obvious, for what it's worth, arara. I don't have an answer, but I'll look around for some authoritative source.

Comment: One also notes that there are frequently many variants of any given romance.  It might be defining the Alexander romance more or less narrowly.